# how to add some text to a image frame and then get text from the frame

Tags: python, opencv, frame, gettext

I'm trying to add information to a frame of image, then make each frame into a video stream, and finally extract the information in each frame when reading the video. I use putText method in opencv Python to successfully add text information to a frame of image, but I can't find a method to extract text information from the frame again (I didn't find the corresponding getText method, only getTextSize). Could someone tell me how to do it and whether there are other better methods.Thanks!(It would be better to provide some simple code interfaces)

Comment: The text you add to the image with `putText` is rendered, i.e. pixel values in the image are manipulated, such that these pixels then show your text. You don't have "layers" or something you might know from Photoshop or GIMP. You can't "extract" the put text that easily. You'd need some OCR for detecting and parsing the text from the image(s).

Comment: @HansHirse  Thanks for your answer.Besides predicting the text in the picture, is there any other way to extract the text? Because these information is very important. If the prediction is not accurate, such as using OCR, it will cause bad consequences. Do you know that  is there a way to add custom information to a frame, but it does not affect the pixels of the original image, and then the information can be extracted later,like a 'text layer'.Thank you again!

Comment: The only option I can think of is embedding subtitles into the video using a separate text file. That way - at least using a proper video player - the subtitles are shown during playback, and/but data is stored separately. But that's a totally different task requiring totally different tools - I'm not familiar with. Maybe, describe more detailed, what you actually want to achieve, and not what you think is the best approach.

Comment: @HansHirse Thank you very much,I get it .